# Why does my static IP address change itself every 24 hour period?

Tags: networking, server, configuration, ip

I'm using Ubuntu as a server running `tomcat` for a web application and my static IP changes every 24 hour period from `xxx.xxx.xxx.100` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.102` and because of that I have to restart my session. How do I fix it?

I'm new to Linux. Forgive my ignorance.

Thnx

Comment: Are you connected to wifi and some other person using your wifi connection?

Comment: Does your server have multiple IP addresses?  When you say static address do you mean `/etc/network/interfaces` sets `eth0 inet static` ?

Comment: No. It's a wired connection, Saurav.

Comment: Rudu, I set up my static IP this way: network indicator>Edit Connections>select my connection and click edit>in the IPv4 settings tab I select manual method and fill the addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your /etc/network/interfaces config file

it should be something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```

there is also the manual that will be of help seeing as you are new :-)

[Ubuntu Serverguide - Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/tcpip.html)

You may also want to download the pdf for future use:

[Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)

Comment: Ok, I'll test it and in 24 hours I tell if it worked =). But thank you anyway.

Comment: I had a problem and had to reinstall ubuntu. When I reconfigure it I tell if it worked.